# JavaScript optimize array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

Hi I'm creating an array

```js
this.data = [{
  label: 'Total',
  count: details.request.length,
}, {
  label: 'In-Progress',
  count: details.request.filter((obj) =>
    obj.statusId === 0 ||
    obj.statusId === 1 ||
    obj.statusId === 3 ||
    obj.statusId === 4
      ? obj
      : null,
  ).length,
}, {
  label: 'Success',
  count: details.request.filter(({ statusId }) =>
    statusId === 6 ? statusId : null,
  ).length,
  additionalObj: details.request.filter((obj) =>
    obj.statusId === 6 ? obj : null,
  ),
}, {
  label: 'Failed',
  count: details.request.filter(({ statusId }) =>
    statusId === 2 || statusId === 5 ? statusId : null,
  ).length,
  additionalObj: details.request.filter((obj) =>
    obj.statusId === 2 || obj.statusId === 5 ? obj : null,
  ),
}];
```

I'm creating the array in the structured I need, but have optimize this, I'm using array `filter` multiple times while calculating `count` and also for `additionalObj`. I'm not sure how can I use filter once for both calculating count and additionalObj. Would be great if someone can help me on optimizing my code.

FYI, this is the details structure:

```js
details = {
  request: []
}
```

Comment: As your code works, your question looks off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-partitionby-method/

Comment: @trincot is working code enough? what about optimization?

Comment: It looks like you are basically filtering the array by the same criterion in both cases? If so, then you can do that once, before the `this.data = [...]` part, and store the result into a variable. And then, it would be `additionalObj: filteredResult`, and `count: filteredResult.length`

Comment: If you've written the code yourself, and you've checked [their help site to make sure it's on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), and you want a full review of the code, you *might* be able to ask this on [codereview.se], but again, read that help center to make sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you are using filter instead of a for loop?

The code can be written as the following, which uses only a single loop:

```js
function partition(details: { request: { statusId: number }[] }) {
    let inProgressCount = 0;

    let successCount = 0;
    const successAdditionalObj: { statusId: number }[] = [];

    let failedCount = 0;
    const failedAdditionalObj: { statusId: number }[] = [];

    details.request.forEach((req) => {
        switch (req.statusId) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                inProgressCount += 1;
                break;

            case 6:
                successCount += 1;
                successAdditionalObj.push(req);
                break;

            case 2:
            case 5:
                failedCount += 1;
                failedAdditionalObj.push(req);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    });

    return [
        {
            label: "Total",
            count: details.request.length || 0,
        },
        {
            label: "In-Progress",
            count: inProgressCount,
        },
        {
            label: "Success",
            count: successCount,
            additionalObj: successAdditionalObj,
        },
        {
            label: "Failed",
            count: failedCount,
            additionalObj: failedAdditionalObj,
        },
    ];
}

this.data = partition(dataToBeTransformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not good, neither your code. But I'm just going to say why you're code is bad and how to fix it.

The most critical thing in your code regarding PERFORMANCE is you're iterating `details.request` multiple times, while you could do the filtering once.

Iterating an array or list multiple times for different filters in this way can be avoided by using `reduce` for your case.

Here is how you can do it by iterating `details.request` only once with `reduce` and create an object that has properties representing the status so you don't need to store that too:

```js
this.data = details.request.reduce(
  (previous, currentRequest) => {
    switch (currentRequest.statusId) {
      case 2: // failed
      case 5: // failed
        previous.Failed.push(currentRequest);
        return previous;
      case 6: // success
        previous.Success.push(currentRequest);
        return previous;
      default: // instead of iterating other cases
        previous.InProgress++;
        return previous;
    }
  },
  { Total: details.request.length, InProgress: 0, Success: [], Failed: [] }
);
// this.data.Total: number
// this.data.InProgess: number
// this.data.Failed: requestItem[]
// this.data.Success: requestItem[]
```

and here is how to do it your way in case you need it data to be in that specific shape for an Api:

```js
this.data = details.request.reduce(
  (previous, currentRequest) => {
    switch (currentRequest.statusId) {
      case 2: // failed
      case 5: // failed
        previous[3].count++;
        previous[3].additionalObj.push(currentRequest);
        return previous;
      case 6: // success
         previous[2].count++;
         previous[2].additionalObj.push(currentRequest);
        return previous;
      default: // instead of iterating other cases
        previous[1].count++;
        return previous;
    }
  },
  [
    {
      // i: 0
      label: "Total",
      count: details.request.length,
    },
    {
      // i: 1
      label: "In-Progress",
      count: 0,
    },
    {
      // i: 2
      label: "Success",
      count: 0,
      additionalObj: [],
    },
    {
      // i: 3
      label: "Failed",
      count: 0,
      additionalObj: [],
    },
  ]
);
// this.data: [{label:string, count:number},
//   {label:string, count:number},
//   {label:string, count:number,additionalObj:requestItem[]},
//   {label:string, count:number,additionalObj:requestItem[]}]
```